# Scala проблема с импортированием библиотек

Tags: scala, sbt

Хочу импортировать эту [либу](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bot4s/telegram-core_2.12/4.4.0-RC2).
Содержание файла **build.sbt**

```
name := "abdesante"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.bot4s" %% "telegram-core" % "4.4.0-RC2"
```

Вот что выдает sbt:

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (Oracle Corporation Java 11.0.1)
[info] loading project definition from /Users/islamshaykhiev/Workspace/bots/telegram/abdesante/project
[info] loading settings for project abdesante from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to abdesante (in build file:/Users/islamshaykhiev/Workspace/bots/telegram/abdesante/)
[info] sbt server started at local:///Users/islamshaykhiev/.sbt/1.0/server/4bd9919fadde7fbdbd5e/sock
sbt:abdesante>
[info] Defining Global / sbtStructureOptions, Global / sbtStructureOutputFile and 1 others.
[info] The new values will be used by cleanKeepGlobs
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] set current project to abdesante (in build file:/Users/islamshaykhiev/Workspace/bots/telegram/abdesante/)
[info] Applying State transformations org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks from /Users/islamshaykhiev/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.2/plugins/Scala/repo/org.jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2018.2.1+4-88400d3f/jars/sbt-structure-extractor.jar
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] set current project to abdesante (in build file:/Users/islamshaykhiev/Workspace/bots/telegram/abdesante/)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last update' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.bot4s:telegram-core_2.13:4.4.0-RC2
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/islamshaykhiev/.ivy2/local/com.bot4s/telegram-core_2.13/4.4.0-RC2/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/bot4s/telegram-core_2.13/4.4.0-RC2/telegram-core_2.13-4.4.0-RC2.pom
[error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.bot4s:telegram-core_2.13:4.4.0-RC2
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/islamshaykhiev/.ivy2/local/com.bot4s/telegram-core_2.13/4.4.0-RC2/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/bot4s/telegram-core_2.13/4.4.0-RC2/telegram-core_2.13-4.4.0-RC2.pom
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 26 авг. 2020 г., 23:07:47
[info] shutting down sbt server
```

Что я делаю не так? Кроме прописи строчки `libaryDependencies` больше ничего не делал. Может ли это быть из-за того, либа для 2.12, а стоит 2.13?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, твоё предположение верное. Эта либа [для](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bot4s/telegram-core) Scala 2.11 и 2.12.

В репозитории [открытый](https://github.com/bot4s/telegram/issues/78) вопрос по поводу Scala 2.13. Как решение твоей проблемы - использовать Scala 2.12.

---

Оператор `%%` означает, что к имени зависимости будет добавлена версия скалы установленая в проекте. В твоём случае эти две строки ровносильны:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.bot4s" %% "telegram-core"      % "4.4.0-RC2"
libraryDependencies += "com.bot4s" %  "telegram-core_2.13" % "4.4.0-RC2"
```